# How are probes in capture sequencing synthesized?

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing

In capture sequencing it is common practice to use a panel containing ~10,000 probes. How are these DNA molecules synthesized? I imagine that there is a way to do this in parallel, but I haven't been able to find a reference to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the oligos are synthesized in parallel on a microchip (or microarray). This is commonly based on phosphoramidite chemistry. Various methods can be used to control which areas of the chip are open to attachment of a new nucleotide, including "[light control, electochemical, and inkjet printing methods](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fbioe.2021.689797/full#h3)."